# How do I do a custom number format for certain values depending on the text of another column?

Tags: format, powerbi, number-formatting

In Power BI, I am trying to do a custom number format for certain values in a column depending on the text value of another column. Here's an example:

```
Type          Miles (Raw Data)     Miles (Desired Format)
PerMile       22.7                 22.7
PerMile       26.3                 26.3
Total         331.424              331
PerMile       19                   19.0
Total         406.782              407
```

Essentially, if the type is "PerMile", I would like to have it formatted as a decimal number. If the type is "Total", then I would like it formatted as a whole number. I would guess that there is a fairly simple solution, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do variable formatting on a column itself but you can write a measure that returns text formatted how you'd like.

Something roughly like this:

```
SumMiles =
IF ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Type] ) = "Total",
    FORMAT ( SUM ( Table1[Miles] ), "0" ),
    FORMAT ( SUM ( Table1[Miles] ), "0.0" )
)
```

Comment: That does work, but is there any possible way of maintaining the data as a value after converting it to text?

Comment: What I sometimes do is write one measure that has the values I want and write another to format that measure so I can use the raw value in charts and the formatted one in tables and matrices. You can't have mixed formatting and use the value at the same time.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your help!